# Composite compoent command button actionListener issue

Tags: jsf-2

Trying to develop a composite component using jsf2.0 (Mojarra) which should render command buttons dynamically based on the list from the bean. The button action and immediate attribute are working fine.Trying to add the action Listener attribute whereas the action Listener should not work for the buttons whose immediate attribute value is true.Could anyone please suggest me how to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can put two mutually exclusive command button into your component, one of them has actionListener and only renders when the immediate attribute is false, where as the other should only be rendered when the immediate attribute is true and it doesn't have actionListener.

```
<h:commandButton value="buttonWithoutActionListener"
                         rendered="#{cc.attrs.immediate}"/>
<h:commandButton value="buttonWithActionListener"
                         rendered="#{!cc.attrs.immediate}"
                         actionListener="#{cc.yourListener}"/>
```